# Toggle button class using Directive in Angular

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, angularjs-directive, toggleclass

I want to toggle a buttons class depending on the state of a form in Angular. The template is based on Bootstrap.

I've setup a directive called IsDirty.

If the form has the class 'ng-valid', add the class 'btn-success' to the submit button.

Alternatively, if the form is dirty and has the class 'ng-dirty', remove the class 'btn-success' from the submit button.

So far this is what I have but it doesn't work.

```
var angular = require('angular');

angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('isDirty', [function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
                var submitButton = element.find('.btn-primary');

                if(element.hasClass('ng-valid')) {
                        submitButton.addClass('btn-success');
                } else {
                    submitButton.removeClass('btn-success');
                }

                scope.$apply();             
            }
        };
    }]);
```

My form:

```
<form is-dirty class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="profileForm">

    <!-- INPUT FIELDS HERE //-->

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save Changes</button>
    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should hopefully fix your problem

```
.directive('ngDirty', [function() {
        return { 
            restrict: 'AE',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
                var submitButton = element[0].querySelector('.btn-primary');
                if(element.hasClass('ng-valid')) {
                        submitButton.classList.add("btn-danger");
                } else {
                    submitButton.classList.remove("btn-danger");
                }            
            }
        };
    }]);
```

[Plnkr Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/4YCXhv0jyAxv5QJEIZmj?p=preview)

**Update:**

It's a little dirty but it seems to work and checks each input, you must bind each input to an ng-model though I have used `$scope.input`

[New Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/hq0DI2DrD6LCgLTelunx?p=preview)

**2nd Update**

I have removed the function and brought in a $timeout you will see from the example how it works.

[New update with a $timeout as function](http://plnkr.co/edit/hq0DI2DrD6LCgLTelunx?p=preview)

Comment: That plunker example doesn't do anything for me. :/

Comment: This example does the same as Kousha's example. When the template loads, the button is given the `.btn-success` class but when I clear the contents of a required field to make the form dirty, the `.btn-success` clear is not removed from the submit button.

Comment: Neither example seems to update the submit button class when the form is dirty.

Comment: I've also noticed that `var submitButton = element[0].querySelector('.btn-primary');` return `null`

Comment: Your updated version works but I don't think the lead developer for this project will like the `setTimeout` calls. I'll also have to change the watchCollection to just watch as the form contains inputs, selects and checkboxes.

Comment: @SeanDelaney I added in setTimeout to give the application a small delay at the initial rendering of the DOM. Without it the directive reads that the form has class `ng-valid` whereas adding a slight delay to give it time to render provides the true reflection. There could well be a work around

Comment: @SeanDelaney updated the answer with a tidy up and removed setTimeout and used angular native $timeout set as a function to the directive.

Comment: May i know why in Plunker i can't see your CSS code in any of 3 updates as you mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ngClass` for this (btw, I am confused with your class names. In your description you say add/remove the class `.btn-success` but in the code you are adding/removing `.btn-danger`. So in the code below, I am sticking with `.btn-success`):

```
<form is-dirty class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="profileForm">
    <!-- INPUT FIELDS HERE //-->

    <button type="submit" 
            class="btn btn-primary" 
            ng-class="{'btn-success' : isValid}">
            Save Changes
    </button>

    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
</form>
```

And in your directive:

```
var angular = require('angular');

angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('form', [function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
                scope.isValid = element.hasClass('ng-valid');          
            }
        };
    }]);
```

I would further suggest that you actually make the class `ng-valid` itself with `ng-class` and use the variable `scope.isValid` to change between `ng-valid` and `isDirty`.

Comment: That was my bad - I was playing around with class names before posting the snippet from my code. The correct class should be `.btn-success`.

Comment: When the form loads the submit button is green. `.btw-success` is applied straight away. Which is fine. However if I clear the contents of a required input field, the form classes are updated with `.ng-invalid` but the submit button still has the class `.btn-success`.

Comment: You need to put the line `scope.isValid = element ...` inside the function that does the resetting. You could also `$watch` for a change in the element's class. How are you resetting your form? Let me know and I'll tell you what's the best way of doing this